# How to reboot my linux multiple times and store my dmesg log at each boot?

Tags: linux, shell-script, init-script, beagleboneblack

I'm using beaglebone board, I just want to measure its boot time multiple times, so for that, I'm thinking to implement one script which reboots after every boot and stores dmesg data.

Can anyone give an idea on how to do it?

Comment: Maybe invoking dmesg like that `dmesg >$(date +%s)` ?

Comment: Thanks @GeorgeVasiliou, but what is the way reboot it automatically multiple times?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12973777/how-to-run-a-shell-script-at-startup